# MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using dotenv to store my database name and password in the root of my `backend` folder in a `process.env` file that is being ignored by `.gitignore`. I have a `db.js` file under `backend/config` that is trying to use `process.env`

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB Connected…')
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

require("../models/Task");
```

But I get the following error

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

My `process.env` is written as follows

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://<dbname>:<dbpw>@cluster0.f9k2w.mongodb.net/quotesDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

With `<dbname>` and `<dbpw>` containing my secret database name and password.

Why is my `process.env` variable undefined?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/quotes)

Comment: You mentioned `process.env` file, if this is your file name, please rename it to `.env` and if the current file is `.env` you can try to reinstall `dotenv` hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your `process.env` file to `.env`

It's a `.env` file and not `process.env` file. Everything else looks fine.